# Trying to input multiple line multiple variable cin input

Tags: c++, cin

I am trying to essentially paste a block of text as an input and get this to work correctly. I have actually gotten it to work using an external text file but have failed to get it to work using cin. Below is the working example. As you can see I want each new line to be a new element of a function input which is where a lot of the trouble is arising from.

```
int uaid;
string name;
float gpa;
int i = 0;
ifstream infile("student.txt");
while (infile >> uaid >> name >> gpa) {
    students[i].Set(uaid, name, gpa);
    i+=1;
}
```

Comment: "have failed to get it to work" is not a useful problem description. "Hello, Chuck's auto repair? I can't get my car to work, can you help me?"

Comment: Is there any to get something like this to work? while (getline(cin, uaid >> name >> gpa) {
  students[i].Set(uaid, name, gpa);
  i+=1;
 }

Comment: use istream_iterator to continuously cin

Answer (score 0):

You can use Istream_Iterator stl.Continously adds to string vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

vector<string> v;
istream_iterator<string> start_cin(cin);
istream_iterator<string> end_of_cin;
copy(start_cin,end_of_cin,back_inserter(v));
cout<<"Pressed ctrl D"<<endl;
cout<<"Below is the continous string"<<endl;
copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));

}
```

use CTRL+ D (for mac to terminate)

```
string 1
string 2 value 
1 2 3 4 \n \d 
everything is there
Pressed ctrl D
Below is the continous string
string 1 string 2 value 1 2 3 4 \n \d everything is there Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Now would this work with multiple data types per each line?

Comment: yes it will (everything will be treated as string) ..as you can in the example output

Comment: copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout," ")); change it to copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n")); \\output in each new line

Comment: you can change  per each line using   std::istringstream str("0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4");
    std::partial_sum(std::istream_iterator<double>(str)